# Messages Extension Send Audio File

Tags: ios10, nsurl, nsbundle, imessage, imessage-extension

I have this URL

myString =
**file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/-------/Documents/MyAudio.m4a**

and here is my send code

```
  MSConversation * conversation = self.activeConversation;
    if (conversation) {
        MSMessageTemplateLayout * activeLayout = [[MSMessageTemplateLayout alloc] init];
       // activeLayout.image = image;
        activeLayout.caption = @"Message Counter";
        activeLayout.subcaption = @"Message subcaption";
        activeLayout.trailingCaption = @"Trailing caption";
        activeLayout.trailingSubcaption = @"Trailing Subcaption";

        activeLayout.mediaFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myString];

        activeLayout.imageTitle = @"Image counter";
        activeLayout.imageSubtitle = @"Image subtitle";

        MSMessage * message = [[MSMessage alloc] init];
        message.layout = activeLayout;
        message.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Empty URL"];
        message.summaryText = @"This is Summary";

        [conversation insertMessage:message completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error sending message %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"No &%#%&^# conversation found");
    }
```

i can't get the audio file for sending i have just Message Counter and etc..

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using insertMessage use insertAttachment-
[[conversation insertAttachment:[NSURL URLWithString:myString]; withAlternateFilename:@"Alternate Name" completionHandler:^(NSError * error) {
            DDLogInfo(@"Error is %@",error);
        }];